# How to hide parsys component in CQ5?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have learned som interesting things I would just like to share the,

See the code below

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <cq:include resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" path="par"/>
</div>
```

We have the parsys component include within our own Div. So when we do

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

We could expect the parsys also to be hidden but it doesn't happen.

Why ? How do we hide this parsys?

Comment: Atleast mention in comments the reason for downvoting.
This is quite a useful post

Answer (score 0):

One thing that we need to understand is that if we need to fetch any CQ related component. We need to use the WCM API given by CQ.

If we inspect F12 our component within our parsys "par" just below our parsys you will see a `<script>` tag.

For example,

```
CQ.WCM.edit({"path":"/content/mycompany/jcr:content/par/modal/modal-parsys","type":"foundation/components/parsys","csp":"pageComponent|page/par|parsys/modal|parbase/modal-parsys|parsys","isContainer":true});
```

See the **path:"/content/mycompany/jcr:content/par/modal/modal-parsys"** property this is the location of the content also known here as **Editable** in the repository.

This is used as a "Div ID" to locate the parsys, dialobox or any content in CQ.

And we use following code to hide the component.

```
var parsysComp = CQ.WCM.getEditable('/content/mycompany/jcr:content/par/modal/modal-parsys');
if(parsysComp) // checking if Exists
{
    parsysComp.hide();
}
```

**Useful info:**
If you paste this code in $(document).ready or $(window).ready this wont work because the CQ components are loaded much much after DOM is ready and is independent of window.

So say if you want to hide a parsys at the onload of page then place the above code in

```
CQ.WCM.on('editablesready', function() {
    // Hiding parsys/editable code goes here
});
```

If you want to hide parsys editbar in Design Mode then go to design mode. Inspect (F12) and find the path value in design mode. It would probably be

```
/etc/designs/default/jcr:content/pageComponent/par/modal/modal-parsys
```

So to get the editable the code would be

```
CQ.WCM.getEditable('/etc/designs/default/jcr:content/pageComponent/par/modal/modal-parsys
');
```

References:

[CQ WCM API docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.WCM)

[Reference Link 2](https://cqfive.blogspot.in/2013/11/hiding-parsys-component-via-javascript.html?showComment=1468507925462)